# Cannot establish connection by Jedis

Tags: java, redis

I use Jedis, and I want to establish connection to Redis server which is not same server where my application running... i.e Redis is on server X and my application is on server Y. How can I establish connection?

Answer (score 1):

### Try with this:

Jedis jedis = new Jedis("23.27.123.100",6379);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the IP address when you instantiate Jedis as follows:

Example (replace with actual ip address)

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(IP address);
```

like this

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(23.27.123.100);
```

Also, is redis listening on 6379 or some other port?  Are firewall/ip tables settings in place to avoid a connection attempt on that port from being blocked? Can you share more details about what happens when you try to connect to the remote host.

Comment: Redis realy listennig 6379 port... there not firewall/ip ... xception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:124)
 at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:54)
 at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:77)
 at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.append(BinaryClient.java:185)
 at redis.clients.jedis.Client.append(Client.java:125)

Comment: just wondering - what happens when you run this (assuming you're running redis on linux) - which IP address does it show to be running on: netstat -an | grep 6379

Comment: also, are you able to telnet from the first server to the second one (where you have redis running) and on the port that you mentioned e.g. telnet 23.27.100.21 6379

Comment: Thank you for answer... there is connection problem, server where the Redis instaled does not listen 6379 port... Hopefully I'll solve this problem...

Comment: great - you can check if the port is bound to some other service and whether the port is open for usage.  best of luck